# Protected Array elements after Object to Array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I just came across something weird. I have a class that is similar to this:

```
class Test {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $details;

    private $hidden;
    private $otherhidden;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->id = 1;
         $this->name = 'test';
         $this->details = 'test';
         $this->hidden = 1;
         $this->otherhidden = 1;
    }

    public function toArray() {
        $array = (array) $this;
        print_r($array);
        $array['Testhidden'] = 2;
        $array['Testotherhidden'] = 2;
        unset($array['details']);
        unset($array['Testhidden']);
        unset($array['Testotherhidden']);
        print_r($array);
        return $array;
    }
}
```

If I create an instance of a Test, `$test = new Test;` and then run `$array = $test->toArray();` the two array's printed out are:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => test
    [details] => test
    [Testhidden] => 1
    [Testotherhidden] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => test
    [Testhidden] => 1
    [Testotherhidden] => 1
)
```

So it lets me unset the `details` keyed item in the array, but it won't let me modify the values or the unset the values in the elements that were private in the object. Any ideas for why it won't let me modify the values of the array? Obviously there is some type of inheritance being passed from the object to the array.

**EDIT**

If I use `get_object_vars()` instead of `(array)` I am able to modify the private elements. So I have a work around, but it would still be nice to know why this happens.

Comment: The unset PHP page has this listed as a NOTE:

_It is not possible to unset $this inside an object method since PHP 5._ Perhaps this is the issue, although you're unsetting properties of $this

Comment: I'm not trying to unset `$this` I'm trying to unset an item in an array. Are the values in the array passed by reference and not independent of the object?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you see is because when casting an object to an array like that the keys of the arrays that correspond to non-public properties are prefixed with unprintable "magic" strings.

The real keys inside `$array` are *not* `Testhidden` and `Testotherhidden`. You can easily see that with

```
print_r(array_map('urlencode', array_keys($array)));
```

I randomly picked `urlencode` as a very convenient way of transforming unprintable characters to printable representations, but of course any other function with that property would serve as well.

Comment: You are correct if I modify the `print_r` as you have shown, it shows that `%00Test%00hidden` is the key. So is it not possible to modify these elements in the array?

Comment: @Pitchinnate: Sure it is, but you have to use the actual keys: `unset($array["\x00Test\x00hidden"]);`

Comment: thanks, I wonder why the documentation says nothing about this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting it just says the class name is appended to the front, nothing about the other characters.

Comment: @Pitchinnate: *"These prepended values have null bytes on either side."* ;-)

Comment: Next time I'll read the whole paragraph not just one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This post will answer your questions.

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/get-only-public-class-properties-for-current-class-in-php/

But basically you get the properties because of the scope in which `get_object_vars()` is called. But if you change the scope as outlined in the post you should get the results you are looking for.

```
public function toArray()
{
    $getFields = function($obj) { return get_object_vars($obj); };
    return $getFields($this);
}
```

Comment: While useful knowledge, this has nothing to do with the matter at hand.

Comment: @Jon completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump will show you the answer. The Array keys for protected properties are turning into 
`"\0Test\0otherhidden"` and `"\0Test\0hidden"`. print_r is masking this fact from you.